# SBT plugin - User defined configuration for Command via their build.sbt

Tags: scala, configuration, sbt, settings, sbt-plugin

**I'm writing an SBT Plugin that adds a Command and would like users to be able to configure this Command by setting variables in their `build.sbt`. What is the simplest way to achieve this?**

Here is an simplified example of what the Plugin looks like:

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object MyPlugin extends Plugin {

  override lazy val settings = Seq(commands += Command.args("mycommand", "myarg")(myCommand))

  def myCommand = (state: State, args: Seq[String]) => {

    //Logic for command...

    state
  }
}
```

I would like someone to be able to add the follow to their `build.sbt` file:

```
newSetting := "light"
```

How do I make this available as a `String` variable from inside the `myCommand` Command above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the example here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins.html#example-plugin

In this example, a task and setting are defined:

```
val newTask = TaskKey[Unit]("new-task")
val newSetting = SettingKey[String]("new-setting")

val newSettings = Seq(
  newSetting := "test",
  newTask <<= newSetting map { str => println(str) }
)
```

A user of your plugin could then provide their own value for the `newSetting` setting in their *build.sbt*:

```
newSetting := "light"
```

**EDIT**

Here's another example, closer to what you're going for:

*Build.scala*:

```
import sbt._                                                
import Keys._                                               

object HelloBuild extends Build {                           

    val newSetting = SettingKey[String]("new-setting", "a new setting!")

    val myTask = TaskKey[State]("my-task")                  

    val mySettings = Seq(                                   
      newSetting := "default",                              
      myTask <<= (state, newSetting) map { (state, newSetting) =>  
        println("newSetting: " + newSetting)                
        state
      }
    )

    lazy val root =
      Project(id = "hello",
              base = file("."),
              settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ mySettings)            
}
```

With this configuration, you can run `my-task` at the sbt prompt, and you'll see `newSetting: default` printed to the console.

You can override this setting in *build.sbt*:

```
newSetting := "modified"
```

Now, when you run `my-task` at the sbt prompt, you'll see `newSetting: modified` printed to the console.

**EDIT 2**

Here's a stand-alone version of the example above: https://earldouglas.com/ext/stackoverflow.com/questions/17038663/

Comment: I tried this out, but didn't have much joy. TBH, I'm not sure what a `TaskKey` is so think I need to read up some more on that. I've edited the question to be more specific about my use case, which is an SBT plugin that adds an SBT `Command` and added a code example of what I currently have. Let me know if you have any ideas where I could be going wrong.

Comment: Found some quite good documentation [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#define-the-key) and Tasks and Commands look pretty similar. (Also mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/vgxkDSgOnlc/BQyKT7nOYnQJ)) I think tomorrow I'll try migrating away from using `Command`s to using `Task`s.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example a bit closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: I've got this working inside a plugin - thanks for your help. I'll add some more to your answer later about some other problems I faced, if that is ok?

Comment: Sure thing, feel free to add to my answer.

Comment: @James I'm a little confused about the example link you gave.  How are the build.sbt and My.plugin connected?  I don't see any common key or naming between them.  Would you please explain?

Comment: @orange80 I'm not sure what you refer to by *My.plugin*, but I put together a minimal example that requires only a Build.scala and a build.sbt.  You can check it out here: https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/sbt-custom-task

Comment: @James Sorry it's MyPlugin.scala, that's how they have it at the scala-sbt link at the top of this answer.  I'll check out the one you just posted, much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted @James's answer as it really helped me out. I moved away from using a Commands in favour of a Task (see [this mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/vgxkDSgOnlc/8OPkYlikmmAJ)). In the end my plugin looked something like this:

```
package packge.to.my.plugin

import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object MyPlugin extends Plugin {

  import MyKeys._

  object MyKeys {
    val myTask = TaskKey[Unit]("runme", "This means you can run 'runme' in the SBT console")
    val newSetting = SettingKey[String]("newSetting")
  }

  override lazy val settings = Seq (
    newSetting := "light",
    myTask <<= (state, newSetting) map myCommand
  )

  def myCommand(state: State, newSetting: String) {
    //This code runs when the user types the "runme" command in the SBT console
    //newSetting is "light" here unless the user overrides in their build.sbt (see below)
    state.log.info(newSetting)
  }
}
```

To override the `newSetting` in the `build.sbt` of a project that uses this plugin:

```
import packge.to.my.plugin.MyKeys._

newSetting := "Something else"
```

The missing import statement had me stuck for a while!

Comment: are you sure that import is allowed in an `.sbt` file?

Comment: Yes, although it has to be at the very top of the file.