# Overriding settings per user in SBT?

Tags: sbt

Given a `build.sbt` which is committed to a code repository, what is a general pattern which allows users to override setting values defined in this script?

On the surface, this appears to have been answered in [Where should local settings (per user, and not version-controlled) go in newer (0.10+) versions of SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666904/where-should-local-settings-per-user-and-not-version-controlled-go-in-newer).  The answer there is to simply define two scripts in the same directory -- `build.sbt` and `local.sbt`, and rely on the fact that sbt will combine these scripts together.  This may work for augmenting values (i.e., appending lists), but I don't see how it works for overriding the script value, since if a setting's value is set in both scripts, I don't know which of the two values will survive after sbt has combined the scripts.

It could be that I'm missing something very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `~/.sbt/0.13` global directory where your `.sbt` files are processed during project load and **after** the other files in the project itself.

I found `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt` a good place for global settings - the name always hints me for its purpose.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve a similar effect on a per-project basis?  I suspect we probably need to override settings on a per-project (in addition to per-user) basis.